# Facebox - Loading a form inside a div destroys the form's uniqueness

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebox

So, I'm using Facebox 1.3 (latest)

I call facebox with a link like this:

```
<a href="#dialog" class="comment action_button" rel="facebox">comment</a>
```

`#dialog` is a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialog" style="display: none">              
    <form id="redline_form">
        <textarea id="suggested_text" name="suggested_text" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></textarea>

        <br>
        <!-- submit button here -->
    </form>

</div>
```

So, I read that when facebox loads a div into itself, it clones the DOM elements. That would be ok, except for my submit buttons are actually AJAX calls that also submit the form by the form's ID.  and since ID is no longer unique, it submits the original form, rather than the one iside the facebox (which you can get to by adding `#facebox` to the selectors).

How do I make it so the form remains unique and doesn't get cloned. or maybe, there is a way to specify the form id in Ruby on Rails' link_to_remote?

```
<%= link_to_remote "Submit Comment",
    :url => { :action => :create_redline_comment_or_change, 
    :commit => "Submit Comment" },
    :submit => "redline_form",
    :html => {:id => "comment_submit"} %>
```

here with the :submit parameter, I tried doing #facebox #redline_form, but it doesn't know how to interpret that apparently. (no request sent to the server). The way it is now, it sends a request to the server, but it sends the non-facebox form. =\

Using Rails 2.3.8

The relevant Javascript for the workflow displayed here:

```
    jQuery(".comment").click(function(){
        $j("div#rl_menu").fadeOut(100);

        $j(".original_text").html('' + $selected_text);
        $j("textarea#suggested_text").html("Enter your comment(s) then click submit.");
        $j("#comment_submit").show();
        $j("#change_submit").hide();

        form = $j("#facebox #redline_form_fake");
        form.attr("id", "redline_form");
        form.attr("name", "redline_form");

        field = $j("#facebox #redline_form #suggested_text_fake");
        field.attr("id", "suggested_text");
        field.attr("name", "suggested_text");
    });
```

EDIT: added code that is supposed to change the ids of the form elements inside the facebox, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could add your javascript code to the post? Because the problem will most likely in the javascript side

Comment: Having tried the demo, it does seem to clone the contents as described. I can't help with the Rails side of things (which may well be a better place to solve the problem, as you say), but one possible way round it would be to hook into the `facebox.reveal` event and change the form ID to something unique.

Comment: I posted some js, it isn't gonna help though =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: was to instead of load a div that was already on the page (which get's cloned, and causes issues with multiple elements with the same ID), to put the form into a partial, and load that partial into the facebox.

For non-web-appers, it's just loading an URL that contains the div. =D

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Facebox 1.3 and jQuery Validation Plugin and have a form that creates a new user with a form.

```
                <a onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'includes/cuser_form.inc' })"
```

I had the same problem and tried your approach TheLindyHop, (not firstly without trying replacing the id and name of the form, which didn't work for me because the field elements are required to have specific names for entering those values into the DB, .. it's needed to preserve the names and id's of those fields.. else if this would have not been critical, you could somehow detect the input elements when Facebox is cloning the element.. you will need to check which version the op is using) and it worked like a charm.. so basically I was including an .inc file with the div contents for the form.. and after using this approach but without the href (tried href="javascript:void(0);"
 and then removed it and did the same so, this seems to be the correct answer.. needs to be done with AJAX )